# How can I specify a relationship with respect to referenced tables existing reference?

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-relationship

This is probably a design flaw and there's likely a better way to achieve what I want, but.

I have three tables: Managers, Employees and C. Managers and Employees have a one-to-many relationship as such:

```
CREATE TABLE Managers (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Employees (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    manager_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) references Managers(id)
);
```

Listing:

```
Table Managers:

id | name
-----------
1  | Eve
2  | Amber


Table Employees:

id | name    | manager_id
-------------------
1  | George  | 1
2  | Cecilia | 1
3  | Steve   | 2
4  | Martin  | 2
```

Now, I would like to have table C (can't think of a name that would make sense in this specific example) with a reference to Employees such that for every entry in C there's one employee per manager. Could look like this:

```
Table C:

id | name    | employee_id
--------------------------
1  | John    | 1          
2  | Debora  | 3
```

Adding another entry to C with a reference to an employee who shares the same manager shouldn't be possible. E.g. Adding `VALUES (Sheryl, 2)` to C shouldn't be allowed since employee with id 2 shares the same managers as employee with id 1 which is already referred in C.

Like a many-to-one from C to Employees with respect to Employees relation to Managers.

Again, I'm sure there's a better way to do this that I can't think of now.

Comment: I do not understand what you want form table C.  If in the `Employee` table, you put the foreign key reference to `Managers`  as `NOT NULL` this will force every employee to have a manager.  Please describe the requirement, not a possible solution.  Your question looks like an XY problem right now. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Manager MNG exists.
--
manager {MNG}
     PK {MNG}
```

```
-- Employee EMP is managed by manger MNG.
--
employee {EMP, MNG}
      PK {EMP}
      SK {EMP, MNG}

FK {MNG} REFERENCES manager {MNG}
```

```
-- Manager MNG assigned employee EMP as a deputy,
-- in charge when the manager is not available.
--
deputy {MNG, EMP}
    PK {MNG}

FK {EMP, MNG} REFERENCES employee {EMP, MNG}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
```